# Integer Expression Expected

Tags: shell, unix

Code sample :

```
declare -i a=1
echo "The number of NMON instances running in Performance VM"
ps -ef | grep nmon | awk '{ print $2 }' | wc -l
echo "---------------------------------------------"
num2= ps -ef | grep nmon | awk '{ print $2 }' | wc -l
#num1=${num2%%.*}
#num2 = $(ps -ef | grep nmon | awk '{ print $2 }' | wc -l)
echo "---------------------------------------------"
echo "${num2}"
while [ "$a" -lt "$num2" ]
do
kill -USR2 $(ps -ef | grep nmon | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1)
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

In the Output i am getting the following error 
[: : integer expression expected

in the debug it shows 
++ '[' 1 -lt '' ']'

that num2 is empty but when i echo the num2 value i am getting the value correctly.

Output:

The number of NMON instances running in Performance VM

### 1

### 1

thanks in advance

Comment: `num2= ps -ef | grep nmon | awk '{ print $2 }' | wc -l` should be `num2=$(ps -ef | awk '/nmon/{ print $2 }' | wc -l)`

Comment: "... but when i echo the num2 value i am getting the value correctly." No you aren't.

Comment: Voting to close. If you don't listen to good advice, we can't help.

Comment: `num2= ` that's invalid syntax. Well, technically valid, but I'm sure you don't have an app called `num2=`.

Comment: @anubhava i have added your correction to the above but it gives me the following output 
num2: command not found

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i have edited my sample code as requested ... kindly me know it needs anything else

Comment: Not as requested. Whitespaces matter.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's perfectly valid, it just doesn't do what the OP expects. It assigns an empty string to the variable `num2` for the duration of the pipeline.

Comment: @tripleee: Oh *censored*, I forgot about that one. Thx;)

Comment: Thank you so much everyone ... hope to keep learning from you all

Answer (score 1):

The 1 you see in the output is not from `echo "${num2}"`.  Like the diagnostics already tell you, this variable is empty.

The general syntax of shell scripts is

```
[ variable=value ...] command parameters ...
```

which will assign `value` to `variable` for the duration of `command`, then restore its original value.  So the pipeline you are running temporarily sets `num2` to the empty string (which apparently it already contained anyway), then runs the pipeline without storing the output anywhere (such as, I imagine you expected, in `num2`).

Here is a fixed version of your script, with the additional change that the Awk scripts handle stuff you used `grep` and `head` and `wc` for.  Because the functionality of these commands is easily replaced within Awk, using external utilities is doubtful (especially so for `grep` which really is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) when you just run it as a preprocessor for a simple Awk script).

```
countnmon () {
    ps -ef | awk '/[n]mon/ { ++n } END { print n }'
}
declare -i a=1
echo "The number of NMON instances running in Performance VM"
countnmon
echo "---------------------------------------------"
num2=$(countnmon)
#num1=${num2%%.*}
#num2 = $(countnmon)
echo "---------------------------------------------"
echo "${num2}"
while [ "$a" -lt "$num2" ]
do
  kill -USR2 $(ps -ef | awk '/[n]mon/ { print $2; exit }')
  a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

The repeated code could be refactored even further to avoid all code duplication but that will somewhat hamper the readability of this simple script so I have not done that.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespaces matter in bash.

The syntax for command execution is:

```
command arg1 arg2 ...
```

So,

```
var = value  # command: var,  arg1: =,    arg2: value
```

There's are two exceptions to this rule

- exporting variables to an executed command (the variables vanish after the command finishes):
   `var1=value1 var2=value2 .. command arg1 arg2 ...`
- assigning a variable (you want this one):
  `var=value`

Comment: Just curious, in what way are the exceptions 'exceptions'? Even in these cases white space seems to matter.